# Get a timeline of clocked time in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

In an attempt to figure out how I've been spending my time, I've started logging my time spent on different tasks with `org-clock-in` and `org-clock-out`.

I often find myself editing clock entries by hand, for instance, when I realize that I should have clocked in 20 minutes ago. So is there a way to see a) which clocks are currently running (or haven't been terminated properly because I forgot to clock out before exiting Emacs), and b) a list of clock entries?

I can get a table that shows the total amount of time I've spent on each task, but I can't get a list that says,

```
9:00--9:30   Project A
9:18--10:00  Project B
10:00--11:00 Meeting
11:45--13:00 Lunch
```

which would let me see overlapping times (like Projects A and B, above) and gaps (like the one between Meeting and Lunch). Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`org-agenda-log-mode` or `C-u C-u l` in your Agenda will give you exactly this table. Depending on the `org-agenda-log-mode-items` variable it will restrict the agenda to entries that have been clocked or closed today (that's the default setting). To add visual emphasis to gaps and overlaps of your clocking chunks look into the `org-agenda-clock-consistency-checks` variable.

Comment: Small additional info: While in the agenda view, you can actually directly invoke the clockcheck by using `v` and then selecting `c` from the menu. I am currently developing an extension which allows you to modify the recorded clock ranges directly from the agenda's log lines: https://github.com/dfeich/org-clock-convenience

Comment: Thanks! I think I missed `org-agenda-log-mode` earlier because I was looking in the clocktable part of the documentation, and this is only mentioned in the Agenda commands.

Comment: For me `org-agenda-log-mode` only shows the length but not the start and end time.  And the command `v`(aka `org-agenda-check-type`) is not available: `Not allowed in timeline-type agenda buffers`. Am I missing some configuration or has current org mode _8.3.5-1-g589e96-elpaplus_ changed?

Comment: Look into `org-agenda-prefix-format` to show start and end time.

Comment: Is it also possible to show the TOTAL time clocked today in this clockcheck view?

Comment: On my setup, org-agenda-log-mode shows the clocks from different org files, but not in chronological order. Does anyone know what this could be?